# ssh-agent terminating on network change

Tags: ssh-agent

My work computer is a painfully out of date Ubuntu 16.04 machine. I have it configured such that that `lightdm` invokes `ssh-agent` (not `gnome-keyring-daemon`) and `ssh-agent` invokes my session. This is not too dissimilar to how I have my personal laptop configured, except there I use Arch and use `login` on a `tty` instead of lightdm. My .xinitrc invokes `ssh-agent` which invokes my window manager. In the end, in both cases, X has been started in an environment that is a child process of `ssh-agent`, so every shell gets the `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` environment variable.

The odd thing about my work computer is that when I switch networks (either one WiFi network to another or wired <-> WiFi) there is a high probability that `ssh-agent` will terminate and my session's process will get reparented. This is super frustrating because I can't easily start a new `ssh-agent` and reparent my session under it - I have to log out and back in again.

I have not found any log messages containing `ssh-agent` or even `agent` in the `systemd` journal nor `dmesg`. The only debugging options `ssh-agent` seems to have is the `-d` option to run it in the foreground, I have not tried that yet because it is invoked by `lightdm` and I don't know if I would even be able to see the output.

Are there any debugging steps or known issues I should be aware of with the `ssh-agent` from `openssh-client 1:7.2p2-4ubuntu2.2` ?

Comment: It seems like ssh-agent is running as a child process of something that stops when you switch networks. How are you determining it has stopped?

Comment: When attempting to SSH to another host, the `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` environment variable is referenced to obtain credentials. It points to a socket file that no longer exists because the process that created the socket (`ssh-agent`) is no longer running.

Comment: @Deathgrip just after login the direct parent process of `ssh-agent` is `systemd(1)`, so the parent process of `ssh-agent` is not dying.